# DNS server bind9, nslookup ;connections time out ; no server could be reached

Tags: dns-zone

I installed bind9 on my Ubuntu server 17.04 TLS in my VirtualBox oracle VM, then I configured the different configuration files of the DNS server

`/etc/bind/named.conf.local`:

```
zone "exemple.com" IN {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.exemple.com";
}
```

`/etc/bind/db.exemple.com`:

```
$TTL  86400 ; une journee
@           IN            SOA    ns1.exemple.com. root.exemple.com. (

                                 2018031300 ; serial YYYYMMDDNN
                                 43200 ; Refresh 12 heure
                                 3600  ; Retry dans une heure
                                 604800; Expire dans une semaine
                                 800   ; Negative cache TTL
                               );

@            IN  NS  ns1.exemple.com.  
ns1          IN  A   192.168.0.3
www          IN  A   192.168.0.3
exemple.com. IN  A   192.168.0.3
```

`/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
nameservers 192.168.0.3
search exemple.com
```

`/etc/hosts`:

```
192.168.0.3 ns1  exemple.com
```

When I restart bind9 with `/etc/init.d/bind9 restart` it works.

And then when try with `nslookup ns1.exemple.com`, the output is

> connection time out; no server could be reached

I try the command `service bind9 reload` to see if the service is really runnning and the output is

> cannot reload because bind is not active

so please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Server Fault! Can you be more precise about your Ubuntu version? 17.04 is **not** an LTS release and it's EOL since January 13, 2018, so it's offtopic here.

Comment: yet down the version of ubuntu and answer me to my problem